# Scala-way to initialize members?

Tags: java, scala, constructor

In Java, we can extend the current scope in a method to refer variables with `this` if it is hidden by a formal parameter. A typical example is what we do in constructors:

```
class A {
    int i;
    A(int i) { this.i = i; }
}
```

Now, is there any similar trick in Scala? For instance, I have a definition like this:

```
class A(i: Int) {
   val i = i; // ?
}
```

A trivial solution would be to rename one of the parameters to something else (like using underscores in C++), but I would like to avoid that.

Is there any alternatives for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it *exactly the same*?  Then just declare it a `val` (or `var`):

```
class A(val i: Int) {}
```

Is it not exactly the same?  Then you'll have to use two names.

Comment: @rlegendi and that could be `case class(i: Int)` **not** exactly the same, cause case class is a kinda superset of just class, but even more shorter, if you have multiple public args

Comment: @om-nom-nom Thx, I read about case classes before, but I believe I don't need all those features for my current problem at the moment. Anyway, thanks for mentioning it!